# How can I determine if a device is really running Android?

Tags: operating-system

In our area there is gadget called "IRobot" which the supplier claims has Android 1.4 inside. I am afraid that it might be a "fake" version of the Android OS. I do not have experience with Android so are there any guidelines I can use to check that a device is really running Android? Also, is there a way to check if a version of Android can be updated?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there was never a 1.4 version of Android with any wide release. Major versions were 1.0, 1.1, 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 2.1 & 2.2 so that already looks suspicious.

Comment: You can go to Settings to see Android version in About. If the option doesn't exist, the device needs serious inspection because it's possible that the device isn't running Android at all. Share more in in information so that we could detect. Probably, some screenshots of different parts of system can help.

Answer (score 2):

You could try entering `*#*#4636#*#*` into the phone's Dialer application. This should open up a menu with all kinds of data about the phone.

Comment: Before you enter any dailer codes you should make sure you know what they do!

Comment: @Amanda Is there an overview of all dialer codes?

Comment: @Amanda you said it like that combination hides a self-destruction subroutine :)

Comment: It doesn't give Android version information...

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of Android 1.4, but it could exist. It could be a dev release or something but just was never widely used.

Go to your wireless carrier store and see what OS the phones should be running. Then make a purchase.

Comment: True, and as Android is an open source OS that any manufacturer can download and then modify to work with their device, there's no real point in anyone creating a fake version of Android when they can get the real thing for free.

Comment: I doubt that someone has created a fake Android OS version. But someone could claim they have a device and purposely or accidentally mis-represent the version on said device. I'm not sure what the advantage would be to do it on purpose though.

Answer (score 1):

Android 1.4 doesn't exist. Instead, 1.1 went directly to 1.5; and each release were alphabetically named:

1. **A**ndroid / **A**lpha (1.0)
2. **B**eta (1.1)
3. **C**upcake (1.5)
4. **D**onut (1.6)
5. **E**clair (2.0)
6. **F**royo (2.2)
7. **G**ingerbread (2.3.x)
8. **H**oneycomb (3.x)
9. **I**ce Cream Sandwich (4.0.x)
10. **J**elly Bean (4.1.x - 4.3.x)
11. **K**itKat (4.4.x / 4.4W.x)
12. **L**ollipop (5.x)
13. **M**arshmallow (6.x)

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting and check for device version located at the end.