# Is there an official dialer code resource?

Tags: security, dialer-codes

There are a ton of XDA forums and a decent number of answers here that refer to specific dialer codes. For instance `*#*#4636#*#*` will cause unicorns to spring forth from your phone or tell you what OS you're running and how much RAM you have (I forget which). I found one list of [Secret Star Codes](https://code.google.com/p/android-roms/wiki/Secret_Star_Codes) but I'm wondering if there's a more complete list? Someone warned that some codes can really screw up your phone and it'd be nice to have a good place to point people for good information on what the codes actually mean.

Though in fact `*#*#4636#*#*`, which was [recently recommended](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/881/how-to-check-is-android-real-or-fake/3389#3389), is fairly safe, I think it is a good practice, especially since we all start talking about fire breathing dragons when the subject of rooting a device comes up, to make sure we're encouraging folks to make sure they know what a dialer code is going to do.

Comment: Normally these are for carrier use (and manufacturer I suppose), so I think the only way to get an complete list is if the official list is leaked -- and leaks are not generally considered reliable resources.

Comment: An easy way to remember this particular one is that it spells info on a normal T9 phone dialpad.

*#*#INFO#*#* = *#*#4636#*#* :-)

Comment: Possibly related: [What are the known Android keypad commands (dialer codes)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/do-you-know-other-android-keypad-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=737594) over at XDA seems to be a pretty good start on this kind of resource.

**Edit:** I just noticed that the OP in that thread admitted that most of the codes listed wouldn't work in 2.2.  Bummer.

**Edit 2:** Found [another one](http://forum.androidcentral.com/sprint-epic-4g/34715-samsung-epic-dialer-codes.html).  No indication of whether these codes have been tested and if so what device/ROM was used.